# Lookup autofill with a selected picklist value? - error

Tags: apex, trigger, developer-console, debugging

My goal is to auto-populate the Lookup field with the value selected in my picklist (can be any value).

I have a picklist that has names (text) that are the same as my contact names.
This picklist API is: Appointment_with__c

I have a lookup field to contact that I want to autofill whenever a name is selected from my picklist.
The lookup API is: Staff__c

I made a basic trigger but encountering silly errors and perhaps not the best code as I am a beginner:

```
trigger Autofill on Event (before insert, before update) {
    
    Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
    
    for(Event evt: Trigger.New)
    {
        if(evt.Appointment_with__c != null)
        {
            ids.add(evt.Appointment_with__c);
        }
    }
        
    //Query records and loop on them to prepare a map where key is the name
    Map<String,Staff__c> dclocationMap = new Map<String,Staff__c>();
    for(Staff__c rec: [SELECT Id, Name FROM Staff__c WHERE Name in: ids]) {
        dclocationMap.put(rec.Name, rec);
    }
    
    for(Event evt1: Trigger.New)
    {
        evt1.Staff__c = dclocationMap.get(evt1.Appointment_with__c).Id;
    }
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have Staff__c object accessible/created in the org? Error says Invalid type so check object name.

Comment: Thank you so much, you just rang a bell for me. I made a very silly mistake.